# Error al intentar acceder a una carpeta de un webservice con WCF

Tags: c#, visual-studio, wcf

Tengo un webservice creado con WCF que baja un archivo desde una carpeta que hay dentro del proyecto.
Normalmente para indicar la ruta suelo usar:

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~") + @"\carpeta1\carpeta2\" + "nombrearchivo.txt";
```

Pero parece que HttpContext no funciona dentro de un servicio WCF me sale el siguiente error:

> Error al recibir la respuesta HTTP a http://192.168.0.100:9595/Service.svc. Puede deberse a que el enlace del extremo de servicio no usa el protocolo HTTP. También puede deberse a que el servidor anula un contexto de solicitud HTTP (posiblemente por el cierre del servicio). Consulte los registros del servidor para obtener más información.

Tambien he probado con:

```
HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~") + @"\carpeta1\carpeta2\" + "nombrearchivo.txt";
```

Pero me sigue tirando el mismo error.